# Appending multiple shps from folder to one dataset using ArcPy in standalone script?

Tags: arcpy

I have users creating data (shp) daily into a specific folder, I already know how to invoke GP tools to append these data sets into one. What I am trying to do is run a task (which I already know) to look into this folder and take shapefiles and append them together (same schema) into one dataset in another location.

If I have a folder (call it date) 042115 with 5 shapes inside 1,2,3,4,5.shp I want python to look into the folder and take these 5 shapefiles and append them together to another location. I know how to do this with the GP tools, but each day the files names change and I have to continually tweak the model to accomodate the changed file names. What I was hoping for was a python script that would take these (at a folder level) and start the operation without worrying about the specific names. I hope this makes sense, at a lower level I am trying to invoke an append.management operation on shp within a folder and export to another dataset.

Comment: For starters you can use [arcpy.da.Walk](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000023000000) to look through folders for the shapefiles you wish to append. Walk through the folder and create a list of all the shapefiles in it. Loop through this list of shapefiles and use them as input into the desired GP tool (e.g. append).

Comment: Ok this helps. Would you have some sample code to get me up and running? I know it is alot to ask, but I am quite new to python. Thanks

Comment: Does each folder have a unique ID attached to the file (e.g. Folder1: 0421115_shapefile_1.shp, 0421115_shapefile_2.shp,...)?  How do you want to define the output names?

Comment: Yes, each folder would be the date so for today 042115 (then inside it would be a line and a point feature like JobA_12345.shp (point) and JobB_12345.shp (line)). The output would be static dataset (like AllJobs.shp).

Comment: For each folder then you need a merged point shapefile and a merged polyline shapefile?  How are you defining the output name?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the output would be like: AllJobsA.shp (point) and AllJobsB.shp (Line)

Comment: So are you appending all those shapefiles to a master shapefile or merging all the new shapefiles into a new single shapefile?

Comment: appending all those shapefiles to a master shapefile = Yes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a block of code to get you started. This should change dependent on whether you are performing an append or merge. You will also have to create separate lists and loops/appends for your line data and point data.

```
# import modules to use
import arcpy, os

# input folder containing your new shapefiles
inputFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

# shapefile to append to
masterShapefile = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

# create list to contain shapefile paths
shapefiles = []

# walk through folder and only return feature classes (which will return shapefiles)
# we are performing appends so we want to limit the type of feature class returned - in my case polygons
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(inputFolder,
                                                  datatype="FeatureClass",
                                                type="Polygon"):
    # append shapefile path to list
    for filename in filenames:
        shapefiles.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

# append shapefiles to master shapefile
for shapefile in shapefiles:
    arcpy.Append_management(shapefile, masterShapefile, "TEST")
```

Comment: Yes, that should work well.  Because the OP only mentioned working in one directory, you could also use os.listdir() and only pull files that end in ".shp"

Comment: Like it. Also arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("*.shp")... the one thing you need to address is that shapefiles *can* be different geometry types.. have a look at the answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109075/merge-feature-classes-in-feature-datasets/109076#109076 about splitting them out to points, lines and polygons.